# DataTables - Last column fixed width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

The idea is this :

I have one jQuery that loads the DataTables, and I know that I can set the "aoColumns" : "sWidth" parameter to make one column fixed width and it's working.

The problem that I have is that I have a lot of tables, variable numbers of columns, and I need the LAST one to be fixed size, no matter what number that column is. Sometimes can be 3<sup>rd</sup>, sometimes can be 8<sup>th</sup>, sometimes can be 16<sup>th</sup>, does not matter.

Is even possible ?

No, I don't want to call datatable jQuery for each table, no I don't want to modify anything in the structure because it's working very well right now, just maybe add some class or parameters to the Javascript.

Comment: Hvae you tried using jQuery to find the last column of each table and set its size using css?

Comment: Could we see a sample of the jquery that you are using?

Comment: I solved by assigning one class for that last col, and gived a fixed size. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure your tables like this:

```
<table class="tableClass">
    <colgroup>
    <col></col>
    <col></col>
    <col></col>
</colgroup>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
            <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>    
</table>
```

That way, your jQuery will just need to do this:

```
$('.tableClass').each(function() {
    var self = this;
$(self).find('col:last').css('background-color', 'red'); 
});
```

That jQuery will find the last column in each table with that class, and do whatever you want with that last class on each one. (I just used the background-color to test it out.)

If all you're doing is just setting the width, you might be able to get away with doing `$(self).find('th:last')`, but the `<colgroup>` and `<col>` is the "correct" way to go.